# How to insert a photo into bootstrap card panel

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

A super simple question that I cannot figure out. I am new to bootstrap. How do I insert an image to the card header? I have been trying for 30 minutes and can't find anything online. I know this is a noob question. Spare me. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the image I want to be inserted:

https://media1.giphy.com/media/l0HlSBFa5Z9onGbcc/giphy.gif

I can't seem to place it in the rect tag or the svg tag properly. Any help would do. Or point in the right direction.

```
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm">
                            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img"   aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Project 1</text></svg>
                                
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="card-text">Click "View" to see my posted Project 1. Project 1 is my personal Student Feedback Form. When the form is submitted it will display to you the data inputted as well as give the course and professor a score.</p>
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I appreciate you taking your time here.

Comment: Instead of using SVG, why not try using the Image-tag.

`<img src="/image.jpg" alt="Card Image">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace this:

```
<svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img"   aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Project 1</text></svg>
```

With this:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/l0HlSBFa5Z9onGbcc/giphy.gif">
```

Complete code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card shadow-sm">
          <img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/l0HlSBFa5Z9onGbcc/giphy.gif">

          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Click "View" to see my posted Project 1. Project 1 is my personal Student Feedback Form. When the form is submitted it will display to you the data inputted as well as give the course and professor a score.</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check it in action on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/MWbbJPw?editors=1000

Comment: Thank you! So much!

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will solve your problem
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_card_image&stacked=h
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_cards.asp

Comment: Perfect Thank you so much!